# Using variable-precision arithmetic together with functions

Tags: matlab, precision

I want to compute my function with four decimal digit arithmetic in Matlab. But when I run `vpa(MyFunc(), 4)` Matlab returns the same result as when I run `MyFunc()` while the results are actually different on paper. Now my question is how can I use `vpa()` without editing my function?

**EDIT** In the following example my function is `sum()` and as you see the results are the same (`vpa()` affected just the last result)

```
>> x = exp([-10:0.01:1]);
>> sum(x)

ans =

  273.1851

>> vpa(sum(vpa(x, 4)), 4)

ans =

273.2
```

As @Daniel said, I decided to write the `sum()` function with `vpa()` within it, But the result still is the same! What is wrong?

```
>> s = 0; for x = -10:0.01:1, s = vpa( vpa(s,4) + vpa(exp(x),4) , 4); end
>> s

s =

273.2
```

Comment: Regarding your updated question: The documentation says d sets the minimal precision. A higher precision may always be used internally(for example because it's faster due to native hardware support).

Answer (score 1):

To use vpa inside your function, you either have to input a vpa `MyFunc(vpa(4))` or use vpa inside your function. The code from your question is the same as:

```
x=MyFunc()
vpa(x,4)
```

First `MyFunc` is called, then the result is converted to vpa.

I suggest to run your code in the debugger and check the data type of each number. Only if this type is vpa, vpa is used.

Comment: The type (class) of a variable precision variable created with `vpa` would be `sym`. There is not `vpa` type.